# How can we view monoids as lax functors?

Tags: category-theory

Let $*_2$ be the terminal $2-$category, $V$ be a monoidal category with unit object $I$ and $\mathbf BV$ be its delooping, i.e the $2-$category with $ob(\mathbf BV) = \{*\}$ and $\text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*) = V$ and composition given by

$$\text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*) \times \text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_{\mathbf BV}(*,*)$$

$$ = $$

$$\otimes:V \times V \rightarrow V$$

The unit of this composition is given by the unit object in $V$.

I am told that a lax $2-$functor $F:*_2 \rightarrow \mathbf BV$ is the same as a monoid in $V$. The problem is that I just can't get it to work out on paper.

Let $F$ be such a lax functor, denote the identity $1-$morphism in $*_2$ by $id_1$ and the identity $2-$morphism by $id_2$.

Now, a monoid in $V$ consists of an object $M$, a morphism $\mu: M \otimes M \rightarrow M$ and a morphism $\iota:I \rightarrow M$

I understand that we get $M = Fid_1$ but how do we get $\mu$?

The only thing I can think of is that we have an "associator"

$$\mu: M = F(id_1) = F(id_1 \circ id_1) \rightarrow F(id_1) \circ F(id_1)= M \circ M = M \otimes M$$

$$\mu: M \rightarrow M \otimes M $$

but it goes the wrong way?

The "unitor" $\iota : F(id_1) \rightarrow id_{F*}$

($\{ * \} = ob(*_2)$)

gives us a map $\iota: M \rightarrow I$

...that also goes the wrong way!

It would seem that lax functors $*_2 \rightarrow \mathbf B V$ are really equivalent to $co$monoids in $V$!

What is going on here?

Source for definitions etc: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-functor

Comment: I don't understand: associators and unitors in a laxity structure are maps $a : F(g)F(f)\Rightarrow F(gf)$ and $u : 1\Rightarrow F1$, not the other way round; and the $n$Lab is coherent with this convention, so that your $\mu$ and $\iota$ indeed go from the right domain to the right codomain.

Comment: This said... You just worked out the dual statement, that a _co_lax functor from $*_2$ is a _co_monoid in ${\bf B}V$!

Comment: @Fosco https://gyazo.com/d744244cd36a0e7e5da22d0594742c22 . Here's a screenshot from the nlab page I linked.

Comment: Aha, I was referring to the page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pseudofunctor <- here it is correct; at the page "2-functor" that's indeed a mistake, or rather, the cell is invertible but directed as a _co_lax functor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on overflow and got the answer that the definitions on the nLab are wrong. I'm right but have the definitions wrong basically.